# How do I access ASP.NET API keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm developing an ASP.NET application and would like to access the API key used to access the API, for some business logic.

This could for example be for a product listing API where only some products are available to some customers.

I'm imagining something like this where I access the API key in the controller to figure out which list should be returned from the API.
How do I access the API key to make this choice?

```cs
namespace ProductList.Api.Controllers {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProductController : Controller {

        [HttpGet("productlist")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ProductList() {
            if(apiKey == customerKey) {                // <--- How to access the api key
                return productService.CustomerList();
            } else {
                return productService.StandardList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We need a bit more information. Could you please read [ask] and then come back end refine your question?

Comment: I have added what I imagine my final solution might look like. Does this make my intent more clear?

Comment: Righty - how is this apiKey supplied from the client? As a header value? A route parameter? Possibly a query string?

Comment: Its a header value.

Comment: Ok, one more question: Is this the vanilla Asp.Net or Asp.Net Core / Asp.Net 5?

Comment: Its asp.net core. I have also updated the post tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you are looking for a way to access the current `Request` headers.

One way to do this would be:

```
[HttpGet("productlist")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProductList()
{
    var apiKey = Request.Headers["apiKey"];
    return productService.CustomerList(apiKey);
}
```

Alternatively, if you could use `TryGetValue`, mixed with a bit of error handling:

```
[HttpGet("productlist")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProductList()
{
    if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("apiKey", out StringValues apiKey) && apiKey.Any())
    {
        return Ok(productService.CustomerList(apiKey.First()));
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```